# Problem forcing San SSL certificate on Wordpress

Tags: ssl

I couldn't find an answer already to this question, so I'm asking my first ever question on StackExchange.

We recently changed our platform from a GoDaddy managed Wordpress platform, to GoDaddy's Linux platform, and have been managing the gremlins ever since. We paid for migration from the old platform to the new one, and we have been having SSL issues ever since. I'm including a screenshot of the issue for reference. In fresh spin ups of Wordpress, using a San SSL, the issue doesn't exist, but it does exist on the two that were migrated over. We've installed multiple plugins to force the SSL, but a couple of pages still show as being unsecure. The reference URL for a broken page is https://gingerhippo.com/2018/05/customer-journey/ , which still shows mixed content.

[image]

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you contacted GoDaddy support? If you paid for the migration and there are problems with it you should contact them

Comment: Have you tried going into the wp_options table and changing the URL there (in two spots). When I do a site with SSL, I use the "Really Simple SSL" plugin, which does all that is needed to ensure the site will work with SSL.

Comment: I spent about 80 hours on the phone with GoDaddy support, over a 6 day period. Needless to say, the problem isn't solved. Using Really Simple SSL, it solved the issue on all but 2 pages.

Comment: You need to check your browser console for mixed/http resouces and fix them manually unless you are adding some rewrite rules to your server environment. In addition: why can't you edit the source in WordPress backend? Restricted by GoDaddy? That's propably because of the "one-click-install from GoDaddy environment", right?

Comment: Correct. GoDaddy restricts manual changes, mostly due to the vast majority of their users being less tech savvy. Their support department is restricted from manually overriding as well. Something I wish I had known 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find mixed content on your pages use a site such as https://www.whynopadlock.com

In doing so you will find the following image `http://gingerhippo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/uses-of-the-yellow-pages.jpg` being loaded by the page https://gingerhippo.com/2018/05/customer-journey/

If you use Firefox, most mixed content is easily found by viewing the offending page, clicking the padlock icon & clicking More Information and viewing the media that is being loaded by the page.

In Chrome, you can use the View > Developer Tools and select Security and then reload the page. It will show you insecure requests and if you click the offending request (link) you can view the details under the Network panel.

Comment: No worries @GingerHippo
If you correct your mixed content issues you can then remove any added SSL plugins, and set your WordPress Address & Site Address to https:// instead.